# to label a column in a dataframe when a row occurs

Tags: r, database, data.table

I have a database with several orders made by customers. Orders are ordered in increasing time. I show you two of these customers:

```
data<-data.frame(ID_CLIENTE=c(rep(1,8),rep(2,8)),
    PEDIDO=c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8", "B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8"), LABEL= c(NA, NA, "1ER_PEDIDO", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1ER_PEDIDO", NA, NA, NA), 
    DATE= as.Date(c("2014-09-22","2014-12-16","2015-01-19","2015-03-11", "2015-05-18", "2015-10-28","2016-04-13","2016-06-09","2014-10-08","2014-10-12","2014-10-26","2014-11-06","2014-11-24","2014-12-10","2014-12-11","2015-01-12")))

        > data
           ID_CLIENTE PEDIDO      LABEL       DATE
        1           1     A1       <NA> 2014-09-22
        2           1     A2       <NA> 2014-12-16
        3           1     A3 1ER_PEDIDO 2015-01-19
        4           1     A4       <NA> 2015-03-11
        5           1     A5       <NA> 2015-05-18
        6           1     A6       <NA> 2015-10-28
        7           1     A7       <NA> 2016-04-13
        8           1     A8       <NA> 2016-06-09
        9           2     B1       <NA> 2014-10-08
        10          2     B2       <NA> 2014-10-12
        11          2     B3       <NA> 2014-10-26
        12          2     B4       <NA> 2014-11-06
        13          2     B5 1ER_PEDIDO 2014-11-24
        14          2     B6       <NA> 2014-12-10
        15          2     B7       <NA> 2014-12-11
        16          2     B8       <NA> 2015-01-12
```

I want to label all orders placed before and after the order labeled with "1ER_PEDIDO". The result dataframe must be like:

```
   ID_CLIENTE PEDIDO      LABEL       DATE
1           1     A1     BEFORE 2014-09-22
2           1     A2     BEFORE 2014-12-16
3           1     A3 1ER_PEDIDO 2015-01-19
4           1     A4      AFTER 2015-03-11
5           1     A5      AFTER 2015-05-18
6           1     A6      AFTER 2015-10-28
7           1     A7      AFTER 2016-04-13
8           1     A8      AFTER 2016-06-09
9           2     B1     BEFORE 2014-10-08
10          2     B2     BEFORE 2014-10-12
11          2     B3     BEFORE 2014-10-26
12          2     B4     BEFORE 2014-11-06
13          2     B5 1ER_PEDIDO 2014-11-24
14          2     B6      AFTER 2014-12-10
15          2     B7      AFTER 2014-12-11
16          2     B8      AFTER 2015-01-12
```

Should I use data.table function? I have to label all orders by client, and I must to fix clients and inspect all orders maden. Then, I want to label them.

Comment: Is there always exactly 1 order per client?

Comment: Yes @docendodiscimus . Each client can make several orders, but only one is labeled by "1ER_PEDIDO". In this case, client "1" has made 8 orders, and client "2" has made 8 orders too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` approach in two steps:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[data[, DATE < DATE[LABEL == "1ER_PEDIDO" & !is.na(LABEL)], by = ID_CLIENTE]$V1,
     LABEL := "BEFORE"]

data[data[, DATE > DATE[LABEL == "1ER_PEDIDO" & !is.na(LABEL)], by = ID_CLIENTE]$V1,
     LABEL := "AFTER"]
```

Comment: Can you make the data.table approach not to depend on DATE? I think that's what makes it twice slower than the dplyr solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dplyr solution, which is based on @nicola and @akrun answers to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384521/r-replace-values-in-a-vector-before-and-after-a-condition-is-met):

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
group_by(ID_CLIENTE) %>% 
mutate(LABEL=c('BEFORE','1ER_PEDIDO','AFTER')
              [sign(seq_along(LABEL)-match('1ER_PEDIDO', LABEL))+2])
```