# R: replace values in a vector before and after a condition is met

Tags: r, vector, replace, conditional-statements

Consider a vector with missing values:

```
myvec <- c('C', NA, 'test', NA, 'D')

[1] "C"   NA   "test"  NA   "D"
```

How to replace all the elements in the vector before 'test' with, say, 'good' and after it with 'bad'? The outcome should be:

```
[1] "good" "good" "test" "bad"  "bad"
```

My attempt below succeeds only in replacing everything with 'good', which is not so good:

```
replace(myvec, is.na(myvec) | myvec!='test', 'good')

[1] "good" "good" "test" "good" "good"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `diff` with `cumsum`

```
c('good', 'test', 'bad')[cumsum(c(TRUE, abs(diff(myvec == "test" & !is.na(myvec)))==1))]
#[1] "good" "good" "test" "bad"  "bad"
```

---

Or use `which`

```
i1 <- which(myvec=='test')
myvec[1:(i1-1)] <- 'good'
myvec[(i1+1):length(myvec)] <- 'bad'
```

---

Or as @nicola mentioned in the comments, `sign` with `match` can be used

```
c("good","test","bad")[sign(seq_along(myvec)-match("test",my‌​vec))+2]
```

Comment: Nice. To "merge" your two ideas, consider also `c("good","test","bad")[sign(seq_along(myvec)-match("test",myvec))+2]`.

Comment: @nicola's approach is more robust as it handles properly the cases in which `test` is placed at first or last position while the other two might fail.

Comment: @989 Anyway, not a big deal.  Thanks for your comments.